# Making a LI an anchor link with codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm trying to understand how I would transform an LI element of an UL to be a link with codeigniter and I'm not seeing anywhere in the documentation that would explain how that would look. I've also attempted to do a google search and not finding my desired result.

I'm looking for something like:

```
<UL>
    <LI><a href="whatever.php">Test Link</a><LI>
    <LI><a href="whatever.php">Test Link</a><LI>
</UL>
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php 
                    $list = array(
                            'Login',
                            'Forgot Password'
                        );
                        $attributes = array(
                            'class' => 'uibutton-group'
                        );
                        echo ul($list, $attributes);
                    ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean "transform an LI element of an UL to be a link". Is that the output you want or something else? I've read your question 4 times and can't figure out what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

[URLHelper to the Rescue!](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

If you're trying to create an anchor, you could just use "anchor" as in:

`<ul><li><? echo anchor('news/local/123', 'My News', 'title="News title"'); ?></li></ul>`

If you're trying to create a list of anchors, using the **ul** method of the HTML_Helper, try this:

```
<?php 
    $list = array(
        anchor('/login', 'Login', 'title="Login"'),
        anchor('/forgot-password', 'Forgot Password', 'title="Forgot Password"')
    );
    $attributes = array(
        'class' => 'uibutton-group'
    );
    echo ul($list, $attributes);
?>
```

That or put the results of that "anchor" tag in a $login, $forgotPassword variable respectively and put that in the array. The HTML_Helper for **ul** outputs values based on what's in the array. Put "strings" of the anchor tag (or what the anchor method gives you) and you should be good.

Comment: `<ul><li><? echo anchor('news/local/123', 'My News', 'title="News title"'); ?></li></ul>`